# Bash script doesn't catch SIGINT while in read loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have several scripts with `while read line` loops that don't execute my cleanup function when I press Ctrl C. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup() {
  stty echo
  exit 0
}

trap cleanup SIGINT SIGHUP SIGTERM

stty -echo
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < /foo/bar

cleanup
```

When I press Ctrl-C, my terminal is screwed up because the `stty -echo` setting is still in effect. I have many other scripts where my cleanup function works flawlessly. The only time I seem to have a problem is when I press Ctrl-C while the script is in a `read` loop. Is there a way to ensure that the `cleanup` function will get called when Ctrl-C is pressed while the script is inside a `read` loop? Or am I just missing something obvious here?

**Update:** There is something else going on in my scripts. I ran the exact script above, and I can't get it to fail the way my other scripts do. I will have to try to distill the broken scripts down to something that I *can* get to fail, at which point I will update the question.

**Update 2:** Okay, I figured it out. I was getting an error from `stty` (which I wasn't seeing because my real cleanup function was also clearing the screen). The error was: `stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device`. I looked this up an apparently it was due to calling `stty` while `stdin` was redirected from the file `/foo/bar`. So I changed my `trap` call to `trap "break" SIGINT SIGHUP SIGTERM` and it worked.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13058864/2591612

Comment: That was a typo. My actual script uses `<`. Sorry.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it once you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the problem was due to the fact that my `cleanup` function was calling `stty`, and `stty` evidently doesn't like to be called while `stdin` is being redirected from a file. Thus, when I pressed Ctrl-C while the script was executing the `read` loop, the `cleanup` function got called as if I had called it from within the loop:

```
while read -r line; do
  ...
  cleanup
  ...
done < "$filename"
```

This, in turn, meant that `stty` was executed with a redirected `stdin`, and it died with the error `stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

I was able to fix this by changing my `trap` line:

```
trap "break" SIGINT SIGHUP SIGTERM
```

So instead of having it effectively insert a call to `cleanup` into my loop when I press Ctrl-C, it instead just (effectively) inserts a `break` into the loop, thus breaking out of the loop and subsequently calling the `cleanup` function via the line after the loop.