# In bash, how to profile the running time of some part of my script?

Tags: bash, shell

In Java program, I usually use the following functions to profile time info:

```
...
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
...
System.out.println("elapsed time 1: "+(System.currentTimeMills() - start));
...
...
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
System.out.println("elapsed time 2: "+(System.currentTimeMills() - start));
...
```

How to do similar things in shell bash? Further, how to collect the accumulated time if there is a loop?

e.g.

```
for ((i=0;i<$lines;i=i+$step))
do    
    head -$((i+step)) $1 | tail -$step > tmp1
    head -$((i+step)) $2 | tail -$step > tmp2
    setstr=$setstr' '`./accuracy.sh tmp1 tmp2`
done
echo $setstr | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; }END{print sum/NF}'
```

I want to profile the accumulated `head/tail` time and `accuracy.sh tmp1 tmp2` time separately.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5015179/1741542

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prefix the command you wish to time with the appropriately named `time` command.

For example:

```
time find . -type f -name hello_world.cc
```

Or in your case:

```
time head -$((i+step)) $1 | tail -$step > tmp1
time head -$((i+step)) $2 | tail -$step > tmp2
time setstr=$setstr' '`./accuracy.sh tmp1 tmp2`
```

Note that time outputs to `tty`, so you don't have to worry about the results of timing being written to `tmp1` or `tmp2` etc.

If you'd like to watch the total elapsed time (since the script has started running) update in real time, you can do this:

At the start of your script, take note of the system time:

```
start_timestamp=$(date +%s)
```

Then start your actual script main:

```
# Do your execution here
```

Then within your loops, wherever you'd like to see output of elapsed time so far

```
curr_timestamp=$(date +%s)
elapsed_time=$(expr $end_time - $start_time)
echo "Elapsed: $elapsed_time" >> elapsed_time.log
```

Comment: good explanation. then further, how to collect the accumulated time?

Comment: @JackWM If by accumulated time you mean the total run time of your script, you do `time ./my_script_name`. If you want to see a stopclock-style update of elapsed time information, see my edited post in a sec.

Comment: I mean the accumulated time of each part, not total time.

Comment: @JackWM if you want the accumulated time of each part (I assume you mean each iteration of the loop), put the logic in the loop in a separate function and invoke the function the loop instead. Then use `time` on the function.

Comment: Can I create a variable `sum_elapsed_time` and do thing like `sum_elapsed_time += elapsed_time` ?

Comment: @JackWM You can; the syntax looks like this: `sum_elapsed_time=$((sum_elapsed_time + elapsed_time))`

Comment: As you're only working with seconds, you might as well avoid a subshell and a fork to `date`, and, instead, use `$SECONDS`.

Comment: And a better syntax is `((sum_elapsed_time += elapsed_time))`.