# How to get/check which parts/lines in bash script takes the most execution time?

Tags: bash, shell, execution-time

I have a bash script which is very long and performs some stuff in the background (without producing any output).

I would like to get to know which lines/parts take the most of execution time.

Can I achieve with some kind of tool/function/linux builtin ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: Somehow it won't help. On redhat 6 I do not have `/etc/bash.bashrc` only `/etc/bashrc`. Even though if I use it instead of the former I am not getting the trace.

Comment: You have to put the lines in the bash script you want to profile.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches here.

1) Log the time each command or function starts at and output to a log file

```
# echo "$(date) : Started function_x" >> $LOGFILE
```

2) Figure out the number of seconds each function/task takes and log that.

```
startTime=$(date +%s)
longRunningFunction
endTime=$(date +%s)
echo "longRunningFunction took $(expr $endTime - $startTime) seconds" >> $LOGFILE
```

Answer (score -1):

When I've had to do this in the past I've used this kind of format: `( time echo "hello" ) 2>>output.txt`

Do this for every line in your script to time each one.