# How to debug a bash script and get execution time per command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a `bash` script which takes nearly 5 seconds to run. I'd like to debug it, and determine which commands are taking the longest. What is the best way of doing this? Is there a flag I can set? Setting `#!/bin/bash -vx` does not really help. What I want is basically execution time by line number.

Comment: Why are you so impatient? Going to spent an hour to shave off the odd second when running the script?

Comment: The script is run quite often, need to optimize it.

Comment: How often is often? It speed is that important perhaps writing in C++ (for example) is a better option. Besides why not post the script?

Comment: Are Perl, Scala, and Clojure faster than bash? Just a thought.

Comment: `bash -x myscript.sh 2> >(ts -i)` When you have moreutils installed and your script does not output to stderr. But the time duration given is of the previous command.

Answer (score 26):

This is as close as possible answer with built-in bash debug facility since it gives overall timing info from the script execution start time.

At the top of the script add this for a second count:

```
export PS4='+[${SECONDS}s][${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}]: ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'; set -x;
```

Same but with milliseconds instead:

```
N=`date +%s%N`; export PS4='+[$(((`date +%s%N`-$N)/1000000))ms][${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}]: ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'; set -x;
```

The last example can go to microsecond precision, just keep in mind you are using bash :).

Exampe script:

```
#!/bin/bash
N=`date +%s%N`
export PS4='+[$(((`date +%s%N`-$N)/1000000))ms][${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}]: ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'; set -x;
sleep 1
exit
```

Example debug output:

```
+[3ms][/root/db_test.sh:5]: sleep 1
+[1012ms][/usr/local/bin/graphite_as_rand_stat.sh:6]: exit
```

Keep in mind that you can selectively debug a specific portion of the script by enclosing it in 'set -x' at the debug start and 'debug +x' at the debug end. The timing data will still show correctly counted from execution start.

**Addendum**

For sake of completeness, if you do need the differential timing data you can redirect the debug info to a file and process it afterwards.

Given this example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
N=`date +%s%N`
export PS4='+[$(((`date +%s%N`-$N)/1000000))ms][${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}]: ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'; set -x;
sleep 1
for ((i=0;i<2;i++)); do
        o=$(($RANDOM*$RANDOM/$RANDOM))
        echo $o
        sleep 0.$o
done
exit
```

Run it while redirecting debug to a file:

```
./example.sh 2>example.dbg
```

And output the differential debug timing with this (covers multi-line):

```
p=0; cat example.dbg | while read l; do [[ ! ${l%%[*} =~ ^\+ ]] && echo $l && continue; i=`echo $l | sed 's#[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*#\1#'`; echo $l | sed "s#${i}ms#${i}ms+$(($i-$p))ms#"; p=$i; done
```

The output:

```
+[2ms+2ms][./example.sh:5]: sleep 1
+[1006ms+1004ms][./example.sh:6]: (( i=0 ))
+[1009ms+3ms][./example.sh:6]: (( i<2 ))
+[1011ms+2ms][./example.sh:7]: o=19258
+[1014ms+3ms][./example.sh:8]: echo 19258
+[1016ms+2ms][./example.sh:9]: sleep 0.19258
+[1213ms+197ms][./example.sh:6]: (( i++ ))
+[1217ms+4ms][./example.sh:6]: (( i<2 ))
+[1220ms+3ms][./example.sh:7]: o=176
+[1226ms+6ms][./example.sh:8]: echo 176
+[1229ms+3ms][./example.sh:9]: sleep 0.176
+[1442ms+213ms][./example.sh:6]: (( i++ ))
+[1460ms+18ms][./example.sh:6]: (( i<2 ))
+[1502ms+42ms][./example.sh:11]: exit
```

Comment: Very nicely done. The question is tagged `linux`, but since the techniques are potentially useful on all platforms that support bash, let me add: sadly, `%N` doesn't work with `date` on BSD/OSX, so the milliseconds variant doesn't work there.

Comment: The milliseconds variant also does that, but to also get the `$SECONDS` variant to start measuring from the point where `set -x` is run, execute `SECONDS=0` first. Finally, it's worth mentioning that the act of measuring itself will increase execution time slightly, less so with the `$SECONDS` approach.

Comment: Very nice answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: @mklement0 to make it work on BSD/macOS, you can use the GNU variants of the tools `date` and `sed`, which you can install using Homebrew or Macports on macOS (and I presume Ports has them on BSD).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `time` utility to measure the run time of your individual commands/functions.

For example:

```
[ben@imac ~]$ cat times.sh
#!/bin/bash

test_func ()
{
    sleep 1
    echo "test"
}

echo "Running test_func()"
time test_func
echo "Running a 5 second external command"
time sleep 5
```

Running that script results in something like the following:

```
[ben@imac ~]$ ./times.sh
Running test_func()
test

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
Running a 5 second external command

real    0m5.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: do not use `test` as function name. It's a shell built-in. rename it to `test_time` or something...

Comment: A nitpick: `time` is by default a _shell keyword_ (while also existing as an external utility, `/usr/bin/time`). Only the shell keyword is capable of measuring arbitrary shell commands _as a whole_ (compare the output from `time ls | sleep 1` to `/usr/bin/time ls | sleep 1`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set -x` to have the script print each command before it's executed. I don't know of a way to get command timings added automatically. You can sprinkle `date` commands throughout the script to mark the time.

Comment: You could combine this with ts from moreutils

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^\([^#]\)/time \1/' script.sh>tmp.sh && ./tmp.sh
```

it prepends a time command to all the non command lines

Comment: This doesn't always work: consider `for i in {1..3}\ndo\necho $i\ndone`.  Something simple, but `time do` and `time done` aren't valid

Comment: This is true, but it at least allows some degree of automation. I like the idea, it has to be improved though...