# Capture -x debug commands into a file in Bash

Tags: bash, debugging

Using `set -x` in bash prints the shell-expanded commands to stderr.
I would like to redirect these to a file or pipe.
But not the whole output - only some commands.
Something like:

```
set -x command.txt  ### <-- command.txt param is made up
echo $A $B
set +x
```

This would put the debug output to command. txt.

Can this be done?

Comment: Found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself , only works for stdout.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With `bash` 4.1 or later:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 5> command.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"

echo -n "hello "

set -x
echo -n world
set +x

echo "!"
```

Output to stdout (FD 1):

```
hello world!
```

Output to command.txt (FD 5):

```
+ echo -n world
+ set +x
```

Comment: like any good logger, each line should have a timestamp. is there a way to get a timestamp using this method of creating a file descriptor `5`, and log the current time of the line being executed?

Comment: @activedecay: *If you have access to logger command then you can use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155553/74329) to write debug output via your syslog with timestamp, script name and line number.*