# Do I need stay away from bash scripts for big files?

Tags: bash

I have big log files(1-2 gb and more). I'm new on programming and bash so useful and easy for me. When I need something, I can do (someone help me on here). Simple scripts works fine, but when I need complex operations, maybe bash so slow maybe my programming skill so bad, it's so slow working.

So do I need C for complex programming on my server log files or do I need just optimization my scripts?

If I need just optimization, how can I check where is bad or where is good on my codes?

---

For example I have while-do loop:

```
  while read -r date month size;
  do  
  ...
  ...
  done < file.tmp
```

How can I use awk for faster run?

Comment: see similar question on bash script profiling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: Of course, you're making sure that your Bash style is already optimal: avoiding unnecessary subshells, reading files unnecessarily too many times, adopting the good algorithm, using builtins instead of external commands as much as possible, etc.

Comment: How can I check this if I don't know where is bad or good? Any tool or something?

Comment: What are the commands you are using , So that we can determine which command is slower.

Comment: Ya, like Sriharsha Kalluru said, you need to tell us what those `...` are, for us to decide which way is better. (And how to convert it to awk..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you use bash. To illustrate, consider how you'd sum a possibly large number of integers.

This function does what Bash was meant for: being control logic for calling other utilities.

```
sumlines_fast() {
   awk '{n += $1} END {print n}'
}
```

It runs in 0.5 seconds on a million line file. That's the kind of bash code you can very effectively use for larger files.

---

Meanwhile, this function does what Bash is not intended for: being a general purpose programming language:

```
sumlines_slow() {
   local i=0
   while IFS= read -r line
   do
     (( i += $line ))
   done
   echo "$i"
}
```

This function is slow, and takes 30 seconds to sum the same million line file. You should not be doing this for larger files.

---

Finally, here's a function that could have been written by someone who has no understanding of bash at all:

```
sumlines_garbage() {
   i=0
   for f in `cat`
   do
     i=`echo $f + $i | bc`
   done
   echo $i 
}
```

It treats forks as being free and therefore runs ridiculously slowly. It would take something like five hours to sum the file. You should not be using this at all.

Comment: Thank you. Edited my question, how can I use awk for my loop?