# Creating timestamps for "echo" outputs to file

Tags: linux, windows, bash, unix, cygwin

I'm trying to create a timestamp for the information produced from the below .sh file when it is ran and the "echo"'s are performed. What is the best way to go about doing this?

```
echo "Target File" >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
if [ -f //TargetDirectory/TargetFile ]
then
    echo //TargetDirectory/TargetFile is present. >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
else
    echo //TargetDirectory/TargetFile is missing. >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
fi
echo -e "\n" >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo () {
    builtin echo "$(date +'[%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'):" "$@"
}
```

Just override echo.

Comment: This might be a bit better `builtin echo "$(date +'[%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'):"  "$@"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to timestamp *all* output (to `STDOUT`) from your script, not just that produced by `echo`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

timestamp () {
    while read -r line
    do
        echo "$(date --iso-8601=ns) $line"
    done
}

exec > >(timestamp)

echo "Target File" >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
if [ -f //TargetDirectory/TargetFile ]
then
    echo //TargetDirectory/TargetFile is present. >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
else
    echo //TargetDirectory/TargetFile is missing. >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
fi
echo -e "\n" >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
printf '%s' "something"
whoami
```

If you're trying to profile the execution of a script, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015179/26428).

Answer (score 1):

I would write a log function.

```
function log()
{
    echo "$(date +'[%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'):" $* >> /cygdrive/c/FilePath/Log.txt
}

log "Target File"
if [ -f //TargetDirectory/TargetFile ]
then
    log //TargetDirectory/TargetFile is present.
else
    log //TargetDirectory/TargetFile is missing.
fi
log -e "\n"
```

Comment: [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and [$* vs "$@"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Special_Parameters)