# Get both duration time of a command and the command result

Tags: bash, sh

I am measuring the command duration by the tool `time`, but the result of the command is hidden. For example I am measuring the duration of `find` or `ls` and I see the duration, but not a list of files.

```bash
v=&&X=$((time v=$(ls)) 2>&1 | grep real)&&echo $X&&echo "$v"
```

```bash
u@debian:~$ v=&&X=$((time v=$(ls)) 2>&1 | grep real)&&echo $X&&echo "$v"
real 0m0.004s

u@debian:~$
```

I would like both `X` and `v` variables be reachable. `X` schould return `real 0m0.004s` and `v` schould return a list of files.

How to measure the duration of a command and get the result of the command?

Comment: Everything inside `$()` is run in a subshell, so its variables are not available in the main shell.

Comment: What are your expected values of `v` and `X`?

Comment: @Barmar X should return "real 0m0.004s"  and v should return a list of files

Comment: I'm not going to try to work it out, but I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/capture-stdout-and-stderr-into-different-variables) should help you.

Comment: Note that running `grep real` on the `time ls` output will produce unwanted output lines if any entry in the current folder contains the string `real` in its name.  `grep $'^real\t'` (match lines that begin with `real` followed by a tab character) is much better, but still not really safe (it is possible for a filename to begin with `real` followed by a tab character).

Comment: Have a look at [How can I profile a Bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20855353/1765658), and see how I do ***Performance comparison*** at [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835747/1765658)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code demonstrates one way to do what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

ls_time=$({ time ls; } 2>&1)
ls_output=${ls_time%$'\n'real*}
time_output=${ls_time:${#ls_output}+1}

X=${time_output%%$'\n'*}
v=${ls_output%$'\n'}

declare -p X v
```

- `ls_time=$({ time ls; } 2>&1)` captures the entire output (both standard output and standard error) of `time ls` into the variable `ls_time`.
- `ls_output=${ls_time%$'\n'real*}` sets `ls_output` to the full output of `ls`.  It does that by removing the shortest string at the end of `$ls_time` that begins with a newline followed by the string `real`.  See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${ls_time%...}`.
- `time_output=${ls_time:${#ls_output}+1}` puts the timing output lines from `time ls` (excluding the leading newline) into `time_output`.  See [Extracting parts of strings (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Extracting_parts_of_strings) for an explanation of `${ls_time:...}`.
- `X=${time_output%%$'\n'*}` sets `X` to the timing output lines from `time ls` (excluding the leading newline) with everything after the first newline (the newline at the end of the  `real ...` line) removed.
- `v=${ls_output%$'\n'}` sets `v` to the output of `ls` with the final newline (if any (the output could be empty)) removed.  That makes it equivalent to `v=$(ls)`.
- `declare -p X v` outputs the values of the `X` and `v` variables in a safe and unambiguous way.  `echo $var` is not safe.  `echo "$var"` is better, but still not fully safe.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).  `printf '%s\n' "$var"` is safe, but can be ambiguous if `$var` contains newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary file :

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
v=$({ time ls; } 2>$tmp)
X=$(cat $tmp)
rm $tmp
```